# Python extract paragraph in text file using regex

Tags: python, regex, text-mining, text-extraction, string-parsing

I am using Python 3.7 and I am trying to extract some paragraph from some text files using regex.

Here is a sample of the txt file content.

```
AREA: OMBEYI MARKET, ST. RITA RAMULA

DATE: Thursday 25.03.2021, TIME: 9.00 A.M. = 5.00 P.M.

Ombeyi Mk, Kiliti Mkt, Masogo Mkt, Miwani, Kasongo, Onyango Midika, St. Rita Ramula, Onyalo
Biro, Yawo Pri, Obino, Rutek, Keyo Pri & adjacent customers.

AREA: NYAMACHE FACTORY

DATE: Thursday 25.03.2021, TIME: 830 A.M. - 3.00 P.M.

Nyamache Fact, Suguta, Gionseri, Igare, Kionduso, Nyationgongo, Enchoro, Kebuko, Emenwa, Maji
Mazuri, Borangi & adjacent customers.

AREA: SUNEKA MARKET, RIANA MARKET

DATE: Thursday 25.03.2021, TIME: 8.00 A.M. - 3.00 P.M.

Suneka Mk, Riana Mk, Kiabusura, Gesonso, Chisaro, Sugunana, Nyamira Ndogo & adjacent
customers.

AREA: ITIATI, GITUNDUTI

DATE: Thursday 25.03.2021, TIME: 9.00 A.M. = 2.00 P.M.

General China, Gachuiro, Gathuini Pri, Itiati Campus, Kianjugum, Gikore, Kihuri TBC, Gitunduti &
adjacent customers.
```

Currently I am able to extract the Area, Date and Time using regex:

```
area_pattern = re.compile("^AREA:((.*))")
date_pattern = re.compile("^DATE:(.*),")
time_pattern = re.compile("TIME:(.*).")
```

I would like to be able to extract the paragraph after **DATE/TIME** and before **AREA** containing locations separated by commas. So I will be able to match the following:

```
1.
Ombeyi Mk, Kiliti Mkt, Masogo Mkt, Miwani, Kasongo, Onyango Midika, St. Rita Ramula, Onyalo
Biro, Yawo Pri, Obino, Rutek, Keyo Pri & adjacent customers.

2.
Nyamache Fact, Suguta, Gionseri, Igare, Kionduso, Nyationgongo, Enchoro, Kebuko, Emenwa, Maji
Mazuri, Borangi & adjacent customers.

3.
Suneka Mk, Riana Mk, Kiabusura, Gesonso, Chisaro, Sugunana, Nyamira Ndogo & adjacent
customers.

4.
General China, Gachuiro, Gathuini Pri, Itiati Campus, Kianjugum, Gikore, Kihuri TBC, Gitunduti &
adjacent customers.
```

If anyone could help with suggesting a regex that would help with this use case, as well as improvements to my current regex, I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with a capture group to be used in `re.findall`:

```sh
\nDATE:.*\n*((?:\n.*)+?)(?=\nAREA:|\Z)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bjkUMd/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\nDATE:`: Match text `DATE:` after matching a line break
- `.*\n*`: Match rest of the line followed by 0 or more line breaks
- `((?:\n.*)+?)`: Capture group 1 to capture our text which 1 or lines of everything until next condition is satisfied
- `(?=\nAREA:|\Z)`: Assert that we have a line break followed by `AREA:` or end of input right ahead of the current position

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked and your regex details have given me a better understanding on how to go about similar use cases.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative pattern:

```
^DATE:.*((?:\n(?!AREA:).*)+)
```

- `^DATE:.*` Match `DATE:` and the rest of the line
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:\n(?!AREA:).*)+` Repeat 1+ lines that do not start with `AREA:`
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Voy1lo/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gIGDda)

Comment: Thank you for this alternative pattern. It has worked!